# Objective-C class returning (null) for control values?

Tags: objective-c, class, controls, iboutlet

I am trying to make a TableViewController.. I got it to work using code from a youtube lesson: "Cocoa Programming L13-14" But then when I try to change it so that the default values aren't hard coded... but rather the values of controls in the Interface Builder, I get (null) across the board. Here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSPathControl* pcSource;
    IBOutlet NSPathControl* pcDestination;
    IBOutlet NSTextField* tfBackupAmount;

    NSURL* urlSource;
    NSURL* urlDestination;
    NSString* strBackupAmount;

    //Old--
    //NSString* name;
    //int age;
}

@property NSURL* urlSource;
@property NSURL* urlDestination;
@property NSString* strBackupAmount;

//Old--
//@property (copy) NSString* name;
//@property int age;

@end
```

and

```
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person

@synthesize urlSource;
@synthesize urlDestination;
@synthesize strBackupAmount;

//Old--
//@synthesize name;
//@synthesize age;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        urlSource = [pcSource URL];
        urlDestination = [pcDestination URL];
        strBackupAmount = [tfBackupAmount stringValue];
        NSLog(@"%@\n%@\n%@",urlSource,urlDestination,strBackupAmount);

        //Old--
        //name = @"Yoda";
        //age = 900;
        //NSLog(@"%@: %i", name, age);
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Everything commented //Old-- worked, and interacted fine with the TableViewController. So I am assuming all that still works fine. The 3 controls (2 NSPathControl & 1 NSTextField) are linked up to an Object class:Person in Interface Builder with the controls linked up. Why am I getting output of:

```
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

? When I get to the NSLog(); line? Where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: The `Person` class shouldn't have IBOutlets. Instead, your outlets should be in a subclass of `NSViewController`. An instance of `Person` is a model object rather than a controller. It's best not to mix the two.

Comment: I have been getting that impression the more I consider the issue (as seen in some of my other comments) -- But where/how to access them once I have done that? I have tried putting IBOutlets in other (more appropriate?) classes and then exporting them as properties... I still get the same problem with the (null) - even though the coding seems technically correct.

Comment: Example:
I tried this:
    !class PathsPreferenceController; //ViewController
    !interface Person : NSObject {
    PathsPreferenceController* vcPathsPreference;
    ....
    ....

    #import "Person.h"
    #import "PathsPreferenceController.h"

    !implementation Person
    ....
    ....
    urlDestenation = [vcPathsPreference.pcDestination URL];

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the content of your comments there so that the code can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, technically this question - I found an answer for it. It is to make a custom init method. In my case this means:

```
Person* p = [[Person alloc] initWithurlSource:[NSURL URLWithString:@"moo"] andurlDestination:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cow"] andstrBackupAmount:@"foo"];
```

However this *still* doesn't solve my problem of getting values for IBOutlets from another Class (in this case my TableViewController class) that has been exposed as @property:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
.....
.....
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSPathControl* pcSource;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSPathControl* pcDestination;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTextField* tfBackupAmount;
```

I am still having trouble getting values for these controls in my "addButtonPressed" method with:

```
//ad is AppDelegate - declared in interface as AppDelegate* ad;
NSPathControl* pcSource = [ad pcSource];
NSPathControl* pcDestination = [ad pcDestination];
NSTextField* tfBackupAmount = [ad tfBackupAmount];
```

Comment: I seem to be stuck declaring IBOutlets IN my TableViewController class... I'd like to learn how to get around/avoid that.. just for my own knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

`pcSource`, `pcDestination`, or `tfBackupAmount` aren't initialized when your `init` method is called, so they're all `nil`.  Sending a message to `nil` is legal in Objective-C, and you'll just get `nil` back.  That means `urlSource`, `urlDestination`, and `strBackupAmount` are all `nil` too, and that's why you ge the log output you're seeing.

You need to change the log message to sometime after those variables are initialized.

Comment: But to where, then? The rest of the code calls this Class Object into a mutable array with the alloc]init] stuff, so when would it have the chance to initialize the controls? I have even tried putting the controls into another class and then referencing that class from inside the Person class and referencing the controls as properties of that class -- still no luck...

Comment: I mean, in theory once I press the "Add" Button which calls the methods to add the Person class to the mutable array (for the TableViewController) wouldn't the other controls be initialized as well? --(Read my comments on other posts in this question - I have since moved the IBOutlet declarations out of Person and into a ViewController named PathsPreferenceController) and then exposed them as @property's

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code in -viewDidLoad rather than -init.  It all has to do with the order of events (-init gets called before any of the IB stuff happens.

Comment: As you can see, Person is a simple subclass of NSObject... What else would I have to subclass to get the viewdidLoad stuff? Trying to keep the code as clean as possible.

Comment: e.g. - I'd rather not make Person a subclass of a view/window controller if it isn't necc. Is there another way to access them? Put the IBOutlet declarations in another class possibly? I've tried that but it doesn't seem to be working either...

Comment: You should be able to put the IBOutlet declarations in one of the view controllers and then when viewDidLoad gets called for that it passes the outlets to your Person object.